# How to sort reccyclerview in kotlin android

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Here I wrote a function where when a particular textView is clicked it will sort the recycler view according to that property but the function only does sorting in descending order. I want functionality where when click the text the first time it sort in ascending order and in the second time it will sort in descending or vice versa. Can please anyone help?

```
   private fun sortTheData(){
        binding.statusTextTV.setOnClickListener {

            statusAsc = if(statusAsc){
                vehicleList.sortedBy {
                    it.status
                }
                false
            }else{
                vehicleList.sortByDescending {
                    it.status
                }
                true
            }

        }
        binding.permitTextTV.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e(TAG, "sortTheData: $permitAsc", )

            permitAsc = if(permitAsc){
                vehicleList.sortedBy { vehicle ->
                    vehicle.permit
                }.forEach { println(it.permit) }
                false
            }else{
                vehicleList.sortByDescending { vehicle ->
                    vehicle.permit
                }
                true
            }
            adapter.updateList(vehicleList)
        }
        binding.licenseTextTV.setOnClickListener {
            licenseAsc = if(licenseAsc){
                vehicleList.sortedBy {
                    it.license
                }
                adapter.updateList(vehicleList)
                false
            }else{
                vehicleList.sortByDescending {
                    it.license
                }
                adapter.updateList(vehicleList)
                true

            }
        }
        binding.spaceTextTV.setOnClickListener {
           spaceAsc = if(spaceAsc){
                vehicleList.sortedBy {
                    it.space
                }
               vehicleList.forEach{
                   println(it.space)
               }
                false
            }else{
                vehicleList.sortByDescending {
                    it.space
                }
               vehicleList.forEach{
                   println(it.space)}
                true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a boolean flag and sort accordingly. Pseudo code:

```
    var reversed = false

    textView.setOnClickListener {
        reversed = !reversed

        list = vehicleList.sortedBy { it.license }
        if (reversed) {
            list = list.reversed()
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u please elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type varaible` or `enum`
e.g

```
var sortType : Int = 1 // 1 or asc & 2 for desc. You can use enum as well
```

Your sort function will be

```
fun sort() {
  if(sortType == 1) {
   sortType = 2
   vehicleList.sortByDescending {it.license}
  } else { 
    sortType = 1
    vehicleList.sortBy {it.license}
  }
  adapter.updateList(vehicleList)
}
```